# Invertible Elements of Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Working with a nontrivial ring with unity, prove if $a^2=0$ then $a-1$ and $a+1$ are invertible.

So if $a^2=0 \rightarrow (a-1)(a+1)=0$. Being invertible means there may be elements with multiplicative inverses, so I need to prove that $a-1$ and $a+1$ have multiplicative inverses. I am thinking it means theres some $b$ such that:$$(a-1)b=b(a-1)=1$$ and
$$(a+1)b=b(a+1)=1$$
But this isn't quite proving that they're invertible and I'm not sure where to take it from here.

Comment: There's an error in the first line: $(a-1)(a+1)=-1$, not $0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're close, but you made a fatal error in asserting

$a^2 = 0 \Longrightarrow (1 + a)(1 - a) = 0; \tag 1$

a brief calculation reveals that

$(1 + a)(1 - a) = 1^2 - 1a + a1 - a^2 = 1 + a - a - 0 = 1; \tag 2$

thus, since

$(1 + a)(1 - a) = 1, \tag 3$

both $1 - a$ and $1 + a$ are invertible; in fact, they are inverses of each other.

Comment: Wow thanks, can't believe I missed that. I do have a question, however. If two things/element are both invertible are they always inverses of each other? In this case $1+a$ and $1-a$ are invertible and inverses. If we just had some elements, say $a$ and $b$ and they were both invertible, would they also be inverses?

Comment: @KellyR:  what you are saying is that ***any*** two invertible elements are inverses ***of each other***; that can't be right; e.g., in $\Bbb Q$, $2^{-1} = 1/2$ and $3^{-1}= 1/3$, so $2 \ne 3^{-1}$ . . .